# Delimit by Parentheses with Conditional Statement to Separate Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to split text into columns based on the text found in parentheses and allocate based on the string matches within the column.

The raw content is in the format of:

| Text |
| --- |
| (nytimes) "news on war" (wsj) "news on business" (nytimes) "more news" |

Looking for it to produce the output of:

| Text | NYTimes | WSJ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (nytimes) "news on war with the nytimes" (wsj) "news on business" (nytimes) "more news on ware" | ["news on war with the nytimes", "more news"] | ["news on business"] |

All of the strings within parentheses are known.  I started with this code but an unsure how to proceed. Cannot simply delimit by the news organization, but on the parentheses.

`df['nytimes'] = df['text'].apply(lambda text: [group for group in text.split(regex)])`

Answer (score 0):

**Regex patterns of the news chunks**

It may be more pythonic using `(foo)` as a delimiter, but capturing a whole news chunk still works fine ;)

Regex patterns of the news chunks are `\(nytimes\)\s?".*?"` and `\(wsj\)\s?".*?"`, respectively.

In the nutshell,

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\(nytimes\)\s".*?"|\(wsj\)\s".*?"')
```

**Capture news chunks**

Using the `pattern`, we can extract the target chunks as a list.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

my_text = '(nytimes) "news on war" (wsj) "news on business" (nytimes) "more news"'

pattern = re.compile(r'\(nytimes\)\s".*?"|\(wsj\)\s".*?"')
chunks = pattern.findall(my_text)
chunks
>>>['(nytimes) "news on war"', '(wsj) "news on business"', '(nytimes) "more news"']
```

**Collate the chunks**

The rest is an usual data cleaning work.

```
list_nyt = []
list_wsj = []
for chunk in chunks:
    if chunk.startswith('(nytimes)'):
        list_nyt.append(chunk.replace('(nytimes) ', '').strip('"'))
    elif chunk.startswith('(wsj)'):
        list_wsj.append(chunk.replace('(wsj) ', '').strip('"'))
```

**Populate a DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Text', 'NYTimes', 'WSJ'])
df.append(
    {
        'Text': str(my_text),
        'NYTimes': str(list_nyt),
        'WSJ': str(list_wsj)
    }, ignore_index=True
)
df
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

i Believe this code can be better modified. But it does the job without loops

```
texts= ['(nytimes) "news on war" (wsj) "news on business" (nytimes) "more news"']

data = pd.DataFrame(texts,columns=['text'])
#use extract all to identify selected texts
new= data['text'].str.extractall(r'((?:\(\w+\)."\w+.\w+ \w+?"))')

#extractall will create a multi index columns, and so you need to adjust it

new_1= new.droplevel(level=1)
val = new_1[0].explode()[0].str.split().str[0]
val2 = new_1[0].explode()[0].str.split().str[1:].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

#Created the new DataFrame to better do some cleaning and grouping earlier results
cleaner  = pd.DataFrame()
cleaner['one']= val
cleaner['two']= val2

cleaner =cleaner.groupby('one').aggregate(lambda tdf: tdf.unique().tolist()).reset_index().T
#cleaner.columns= ['NyTimes','WSJ']

cleaner.reset_index(inplace=True)
cleaner.drop(0,axis=0,inplace=True)
cleaner.drop('index',axis=1,inplace=True)

#once the data is is clean to expectation, include it back to main data.
data[['NyTimes','WSJ']]= cleaner.values
data.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `Series.str.extractall`

extract the ocurrences of the regular expression pattern from the strings in the column `Text`, then group by organization and aggregate the news articles using `list`, finally `unstack` to reshape

```
s = df['Text'].str.extractall(r'\((.*?)\)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\(|$)')
s = s.set_index(0, append=True).groupby(level=[0, 2])[1].agg(list).unstack()

df.join(s)
```

---

|  | Text | nytimes | wsj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | (nytimes) "news on war with the nytimes" (wsj) "news on business" (nytimes) "more news on ware" | ['"news on war with the nytimes"', '"more news on ware"'] | ['"news on business"'] |